# Combining C# Expressions with ADO.NET Datatables

Tags: c#, datatable, edmx

I have generic queries to which the return type can be different. Because of this I cannot use TVFs and thus I am using Datatables.

I also want to extend the query of the datatable.

I am trying to do this in the following way:

```
var data = GetDataTable($"SELECT * FROM {tablename}").AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().GetFilteredList(filters);
```

The following is the function definition of GetFilteredList:

```
IQueryable<T> GetFilteredList<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, List<PostedFilter> filters)
```

The logic within the functions GetDataTable and GetFilteredList is correct as they are already in use for mutltiple years. They are however used seperately, as they come from different libraries. The filters parameter contains strings which are the names of properties of the queries. This way the query can be expanded before being executed. This works perfectly fine with static mvc queries on typed EDMX objects.

This code however, does not work for my Datatable. It does not generate any errors, but the filters do not reduce the data either. (I assume this is, among other reasons, because the query is materialized before the AsQueryable function is called)

Does anyone know a way in which I can create the logic which I am trying to implement? (By this I mean creating one large query that is only materialized after the query has been built up completely)

Comment: What is `GetDataTable` return type? And why do you calling `AsEnumerable()` if you do not want to materialize data?

Comment: What is the return type of `GetDataTable`? Also its not clear how `GetFilteredList` applying filters on datatable. How different your datatable is then the existing ones?

Comment: *The return type of GetDataTable is a DataTable
*GetFiltered list applies filters by comparing the property of an object via reflection with the strings sent along

Comment: Are the starting queries really generic or just different in the way the fields are requested?

Comment: @Schwarzie2478: The queries will all follow the pattern of "SELECT * FROM "tablename". It is afterwards that I want to extend them with filters, orderbys and other aggregate methods to create different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that GetDataTable().AsEnumarable() returns a list of DataRow's, while the GetFilteredList is typed to an entity class of some sort?

If that's the case then you should somehow convert your 'filters' to a string in the form of WHERE (Filter1 = 'value1') AND ... and put it in your SQL string you're passing to GetDataTable().